# How do debug Django validation, can't find related object

Tags: python, django

I have the Error:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
auth.permission: 'content_type' has a relation with model <class 'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

I don't see anywhere in the package a reference on the django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.

Even with all models inside a comma i get this error.

I reference user multiple times, but why a content_type error then?

Django==1.4.2

Edit: Because people think my module is named auth, here are the positions where it exists in the whole project:

models.py

```
2: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

settings.py

```
94: 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
112: 'django.contrib.auth',
```

Comment: do you happen to have an app that's named "auth"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under settings INSTALLED_APPS there was

```
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
```

missing. The link to the ticket from jro was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely what Kay Zhu alluded to: for now, you cannot call your application `auth`. The short version of the issue is that `manage.py` depends on several other modules, one of them being the built in `django.contrib.auth`. See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16283) for more information.

The solution is to either reference the troublesome module in your `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple, or (if you happen to have an app named `auth`) rename the module that is causing the name clash. There is a [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8579) for removing this dependency, but I wouldn't wait for that for now.

Comment: My app has a totally different name, i found a post with something similar before but that is not the case.

What annoys me the most there is no stacktrace or so where i can find the exact position where the validation fails.

Comment: There is something with the auth module though, when i remove it it validates.